# Is it possible to create custom app template

Tags: android

When we create new project, we can select pre-defined app template. Is there any way to create custom one ?

Answer (score 0):

Go to installation folder of Android Studio and there are templates in folder `plugins/android/lib/templates/activities`. You can create your own based on the existing ones.

Comment: i created new one but this is not listed in the selection screen. Must i define this to  other file ?